# How to display a 2d array of elements

Tags: jsf-2, multidimensional-array

I'd like to display 2d array of floats in a table on a xhtml page using JSF2 and I have no idea how to do that. I tried to find the answer in google but I couldn't. All examples were displaying classes objects and I was not able to make it working with the table.

The sitation is:
I have the array of some size - the size of the array depends on entered data:
float [][] variables = new float[size1][size2]

After user enters data and pressess button a method is called in the managed bean. The calculation begins and the table is filled with data.

Please tell me how can I display the array.

Comment: Please take a look at the following post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217263/rendering-2d-array-without-hdatatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you can use [`c:forEach`](http://roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/JSTLForLoop.shtml) tag to dinamically buid a [`h:panelGrid`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_panelGrid.html). Just save `size2`, which is the column number as a property and store all the input numbers in a normal [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Then you set that size to the `h:panelGrid` `columns` attribute and the component will split the rows for you. You can also style the content inside the `c:forEach` tag, bordering it in order to give it a table behaviour.

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="#{bean.numberCount}">
        <c:forEach var="num" items="#{bean.numberList}">
            #{number}
        </c:forEach>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

**EDITED**

If you want to maintain the original structure but in a List, you can create a `List<List<Float>>`. That means a List which is composed by List which contains Float Objects. The same as a 2d array.

```
private List<List<Float>> _Matrix;

public List<List<Float>> get_Matrix() {
    return this._Matrix;
}

/**
 * Constructor for BackingBean.
 */
public BackingBean() {
    this._Matrix = new ArrayList<List<Float>>();
    this._Matrix.add(new ArrayList<Float>());
    this._Matrix.add(new ArrayList<Float>());
    this._Matrix.get(0).add(1.0f);
    this._Matrix.get(0).add(2.0f);
    this._Matrix.get(0).add(3.0f);
    this._Matrix.get(1).add(1.0f);
    this._Matrix.get(1).add(2.0f);
    this._Matrix.get(1).add(3.0f);
}
```

In the code above I'm constructing the equivalent to a 2d array with 2 rows and values `1.0`,`2.0` and `3.0` on each row. You can use this code to iterate it over the view:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="#{backingBean._ColumnNumber}">
        <c:forEach var="row" items="#{backingBean._Matrix}">

            <c:forEach var="value" items="#{row}">

                #{value}
                    </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Where `#{backingBean._ColumnNumber}` will be the length of the first array of the List (supposing all of them have the same length).

Good Luck.

Comment: Thans for the answer! The problem is that it is mathematical matrix used for calculations. Rows represent inequalities and collumns number of variables: x1, x2, x3, .. ,xN. The variables are very easy to access in the array and I'm not sure how to map it to a list. Would you be able to write a short example how to use the h:panelGrid and list here?